# Laravel showing request as get in post request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I am sending POST request, Laravel returning as Get request in controller.

My url,

```
http://localhost/walls/app/api/public/api/auth/signup
```

My route,

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
 Route::post('signup', 'AuthenticateController@signup');
});
```

AuthenticateController,

```
  public function signup(SignupRequest $request) {
        return $request;
   }
```

Response is,

```
GET  

{
    "user_type": "1",
    "name": "shihab",
    "email": "shihab@corediary.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "access_token": "",
    "refresh_token": "",
    "expiry_date": ""
}
```

It was working fine,but sometime it showing this kind of error. What is the reason and How can I solve?

Comment: What kind of error does it show?

Comment: no error.. but request taking as get there..

Comment: Can you post the code where you are sending the post request?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that once. and the issue was in the route 
it should be like :

```
Route::post('/signup', 'AuthenticateController@signup');
```

and you've to ensure the request is being sent as POST(watch the network).

sorry I can't add comments

Comment: Not working for me...the requrest reaching inside post controller but parameter not getting.

Comment: `Input::get('email')` return result but `Input::post('email')` not

Comment: I wonder is there anything like `Input::post('email')` in laravel ?
`Input::get('email')` equals `$request->input('email')` and that's what's used to retrieve the request parameters
`Input::get('email')` doesn't mean get the input from a `GET` request.

Comment: oh sorry.. that's why it shows error. but I am not getting value in `$request`. Here $request is form validator class.

Comment: from the code your showing here I think this is your only issue.
the validation will return a the request with parameters if it's valid.

Comment: what do you mean with {not getting value in $request} and if you're calling this function `signup' in other controller please mention that with code

Comment: inside `signup` controller, when returning `$request`, am getting response which I given in questions. but form validation also not working as well as `$request->email` not returning anything.

Comment: you've to use it like: `$request->input('email');` or if you want to use it as an array `$input = $request->all()` and use the variable `$input`.
have a good look on [this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#accessing-the-request)

Comment: finally fixed,issue was in my form request class. :) thank you for your support

Comment: you're welcome @shihabudheen so please close that question :)